# Bash loop through variable (folder names with pattern)

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script which goes through some directories and deletes contents within them like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start job at: $(date)"

rm -rf /my/location/log_folder1/*

exit 0
```

unfortunately, I have these `log_folder` from 1 --> 10. So, log_folder1, log_folder2, log_folder3 etc..

How can I efficiently loop through this rather than write a separate line for each `rm`?

I do not want to use the `find` command to do this - I would like to learn how to loop through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ find . -type d
.
./log_folder1
./log_folder1/sub_log_folder1
./log_folder1/sub_log_folder2
./log_folder1/sub_log_folder3
./log_folder10
./log_folder2
./log_folder3
./log_folder4
./log_folder5
./log_folder6
./log_folder7
./log_folder8
./log_folder9
```

Use a filename expansion [(a 'glob')](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), and a [for loop](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html):

```
$ for fn in log_folder*/*; do 
>    rm -rf "$fn"
> done
```

Resulting in:

```
$ find . -type d
.
./log_folder1
./log_folder10
./log_folder2
./log_folder3
./log_folder4
./log_folder5
./log_folder6
./log_folder7
./log_folder8
./log_folder9
```

Be sure to use quotes around the file name in `"$fn"` so you actually delete what your think and not the unintended result of word splits.

Or, you can just use a glob that targets subdirectories:

```
$ rm -rf log_folder*/*
```

Or, an expansion that only targets some of the sub directories, not all:

```
$ rm -rf log_folder{1..5}/*
```

Which can also be used in the `for` loop.

(I suggest being careful with `rm -rf ....` if you are just getting started with scripting and expansions however. Perhaps practice with something more reversible...)

Comment: These all also delete the folders themselves, whereas the command in the OP only deletes the files in them.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I interpreted it as all, but rereading you are right. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: @dawg, I have a question.. So, I tried using `for i in /home/my/location/a/b/folder{1..9}/; do rm -rf "$i*"; done` - why  dosent this work? VERY curious!

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? `rm` will not report issues with a bad path. Instead, try  the same with `ls`. It looks like you need `"$i"/*` and remove the trailing `/` in `/home/my/location/a/b/folder{1..9}`

Comment: needed an extra `"` - works now.. Bash is such a pain.

Comment: If you try with `ls` rather than `rm` Bash will be more chatty about what it does not like in your path. I think that you are getting an extra `/` in the constructed path and therefor it is a bad path. `"$i"/*"` is unbalanced quotes, so will result in an unintended extra `"` in the path.

Comment: Better still, do `for fn in log_folder{1..10}/*; do rm -rf "$fn"; done` with the glob in the loop and do not further construct the path inside the loop.

Comment: @dawg: this still does not work.. I have: `for i in /home/foo/.my/.location/a/folder{1..9}/*; do rm -rf "$i"; done;` I have it inside a bash script.. It does not delete the folder contents.. I am almost going nuts with this... :(((((

Comment: is it possibly because I have a "." in the folder name? i.e it is a hidden folder?

Comment: it works when I type it in the shell.. but dosent when it is in a script.. I wonder why :((

Comment: As stated: try something that will report a bad path. `rm -rf bad_path` is silent

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with brace expansion:

```
rm -rf /my/location/log_folder{1..10}/*
```

See man bash - Brace Expansion for details.

Brace Expansion Example:

```
$ echo "asd"{1..10}
asd1 asd2 asd3 asd4 asd5 asd6 asd7 asd8 asd9 asd10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **find**

```
find log_folder* -delete
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to loop through in bash - want to use it to learn a bit!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162586/proper-way-to-iterate-through-contents-in-a-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use this loop:

```
# using a common base directory makes it a little safer with 'rm -rf'
fbase=/my/location/log_folder
for n in {1..10}; do
  f="$fbase$n"
  echo "Cleaning up folder $f"
  rm -rf "$f"/* # this will empty everything under $f, but not $f itself will remain as an empty folder
  # use 'rm -rf "$f"' to remove everything including the top folder
done
```